# The style (css) of Angular Material is not the same of the one in the documentation

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

This thing it's starting to annoying me, so I'm here to ask help!
I've started working on an Angular Application with the Material.
I want the exact same style that the material components have in the documentation.

Let me explain the steps that I've done:

1. Creating an Angular Application
   `ng new my-dream-app`
2. Adding Material

```
ng add @angular/material

? Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme: Pink/Blue Grey     [ Preview: https://material.angular.io?theme=pink-bluegrey ]
? Set up global Angular Material typography styles? Yes
? Set up browser animations for Angular Material? Yes
```

3. Now I tried to add a simple form like the one here: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview
   So inside the `app.module.ts` I've added the needed import:

```
...
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and inside the `app.component.html` I've put the component:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..."></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**Exactly as reported on the Documentation**

Now if I try to run the application I have that:

[image]

instead then that:

[image]

I added a background color tho increase the legibility but still I notice that the **color of the inserted text is different from the example**. Mine is black and theirs is white.
Also, the color of the focused element is different ('Favorite food' for me is `#c2185b` and for them is `#e91e63`).

Why there are all these differences between the example and the real working code? (I have selected the same the theme 'Pink & Blue-grey')
Did I miss something?
Is possible to have the same style to the documentation page without override by hand the CSS?

The full code is available here: https://github.com/gixlg/AngularGCCU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

launch `npm install` 
and in your body add the class `<body class="mat-app-background">`, or if you want you can try to add `import { MatSidenavModule } from "@angular/material/sidenav";` in your app.module.ts
and put your html code in `<mat-sidenav-container>`

Answer (score 0):

Try add `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css';` in your `styles.css` file.